# event listener does not work

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Any ideas why this does not work.

The Yes button when clicked works once - the No button does not work

```js
function $(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

var glob = 0;

function new_index() {
    glob += 1;
    return "d" + glob;
}

function play() {
    say("Hello is JS Fun?");
    response("No",
        function() {
            say("Oh dear")
        });
    response("Yes",
        function() {
            say("Great:");
        });
}

function say(x) {
    $("txt").innerHTML += x;
}

function response(Txt, Fun) {
    var n = new_index();
    var s = "<button id='" + n + "'>" + Txt + "</button>";
    say(s);
    var xx = $(n);
    // xx.onclick=Fun;
    xx.addEventListener("click", Fun);
}

play();
```

```html
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Comment: This question doesn't work. Can you please explain what do you expect your code to do, and what does it instead?

Answer (score 8):

It's because every time you set the innerHTML it doesn't just add as you might think, it sets innerHTML to a new value and by that deleting the old elements with the old event listeners attached.

Comment: Goodness inerHTML += x is NOT a pure append operation but has side effects!!! Wow whatever next

Comment: It's because innerHTML is a serialization of the DOM. So it turns the DOM into a string, creates a new, longer string, then deserializes the string into new DOM

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the main issue in your code is that you lose event bindings on subsequent `innerHTML` calls -- No stops working because it comes after Yes. When Yes appends text it breaks itself.

When working with the DOM, it's better to create elements than alter HTML text (with `innerHTML`). In the case of your buttons it means you don't have to (1) create a button with an ID and then (2) find the button. With `createElement` you have a reference to it.

```js
function $(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

var glob = 0;

function new_index() {
    glob += 1;
    return "d" + glob;
}

function play() {
    say(text("Hello is JS Fun?"));
    response("No",
        function() {
            say(text("Oh dear"));
        });
    response("Yes",
        function() {
            say(text("Great:"));
        });
}

function text(String) {
    var node = document.createElement("span");
    node.innerHTML = String;
    return node;
}

function say(x) {
    $("content").appendChild(x);
}

function response(Txt, Fun) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = Txt;
    button.addEventListener("click", Fun);
    say(button);
}

play();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The event handlers are lost on `$("txt").innerHTML += x;`.